# Can someone explain why this sprayer arm wouldn’t simply accelerate to infinite angular velocity?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image: Sprayer arm problem statement diagram]

If mass-flow-rate * velocity = force, then this sprayer arm (frictionless and horizontal to gravity) should accelerate to infinity being the force remains constant. I am assuming I am missing something here - can someone help me out?

Comment: because nothing can move faster than the speed of light

Comment: Okay so it would accelerate to the speed of light? Then my professor is wrong. He is claiming it will achieve some steady state angular velocity.

Comment: Also the spray has to push on something to accelerate to a spin.  Why does the spray not just flow out, leaving the arm stationary? Consider under what condition the static pressure on the inside of the arm arm would be zero.  Every bit of engineering has some degree of error.  You can claim everything is wrong; it's a matter of how close you can get to reality.  Why does anything happen the way it does? Because of everything.  Could tie it to the speed of light or color of the sky for all "why" matters.

Comment: The spray doesn’t leave the arm stationary and would continue pushing on the arm for the same reason a rocket engine will not leave the rocket stationary, conservation of linear momentum. Which in this case would translate to angular momentum. He is asking for an expression of the steady state angular velocity of this arm under frictionless conditions with no air resistance. Talking about how everything in engineering has some degree of error is irrelevant in this problem, he already said its happening with a frictionless bearing. This is a an imaginary, ideal situation

Comment: Keep in mind that the volumetric flow rate remains constant and the arm never loses speed to friction. And it is expelling the water at a constant velocity (relative to the arm). I cannot think of a single way this would not just continue acceleration given this situation.

Comment: The rocket equation. Your exhaust speed limits your maximum speed you can reach.

Comment: @DKNguyen the rocket equation tells you how much fuel you need, but you can reach any speed you like if your payload ratio is low enough. There is no inherent upper speed bound with a rocket because the fuel you are burning at any instant is moving at the same speed. Rocket wheels can accelerate indefinitely.

Comment: @PhilSweet Oh is the rocket equation exclusively used in situations with dead weight?

Answer (score 2):

If there was only one nuzzle the limit $\omega$ would be

$$\omega_{limit}= -\frac{q}{R*\pi* D^2/4}$$

Because at that speed of rotation, the jet is ejected at zero speed from the nuzzle, If we ignore frictions!

- The difference between this and a rocket Nuzzle is the fuel in the rocket at any moment has the same speed as the rocket but the water in the pipe is coming from the pivot at the Q/area speed, if you turn too fast you run out of water.

The same thing applies to the 2-nuzzle lever, except we have to calculate the Q division between the 2 nuzzles

Answer (score 0):

Because the water flowing outward along the arm has to accelerate if the arm is spinning. If you draw a control volume around the device and imagine the supply coming up from the bottom, then initially you have some axial momentum, but no radial or tangential momentum entering the control volume. The device axis can torque in the axial-radial plane, so axial momentum can be converted to radial momentum by the device internally. So water turns and flows down the arm, and there is a force and moment at the axis coupled to ground. But the axis can not torque tangentially, so there can be no change in net tangential momentum when the water leaves the control volume. It came in with zero tangential momentum and it has to exit with zero net tangential momentum. We know the flow rate at each nozzle is half the total, and we are told the nozzles are the same size, so we can deduce the flow velocity is the same in each nozzle (which is an impossible combination in an isentropic machine.) So now you just find an expression for the total exiting tangential momentum in terms of r, d, omega and Q, and equate it to the incoming tangential momentum, which is zero.

What you should be able to visualize is that if there was a small nozzle at 3/4r, at equilibrium the water would squirt out that nozzle and fall straight down as the arm spun out of the way. The inner jet will spray with net ccw momentum and the outer jet will have cw momentum-the arm moving faster than the water is spraying out.